# why Parse.Query is always success even when is not?

Tags: javascript, curl, parse-platform

In a parse.com Cloud Code I have a very simple function "IsNameAlreadyTaken" but no matter what "username" I pass, the "success" is always executed. Why is that?

```
Parse.Cloud.define("IsNameAlreadyTaken", function(request, response) {
    Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey();
    var query = new Parse.Query(Parse.User);
    console.error("Please log request.params.username: " + request.params.username + "<++++");
    query.equalTo("username", request.params.username);
    query.first({
        success: function(user) {
            response.success("user was found." + user);
        },
        error: function(error) {
            response.error("Could not find user." + error);
        }
    });
});
```

Here I'm testing with the username already taken:

```
curl -X POST \
-H "X-Parse-Application-Id: uOXz....rPt" \
-H "X-Parse-REST-API-Key: GAv...SmK" \
-H "Content-Type: application/json" \
-d '{"username": "UsernameAlreadyTaken"}' \
https://api.parse.com/1/functions/IsNameAlreadyTaken
```

and the respond is fine:

```
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100       34 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--    68{"result":"user was found. [object Object]"}
```

The problem is that the exact behavior is when a username DOES NOT EXIST:

```
curl -X POST \
-H "X-Parse-Application-Id: uOXz....rPt" \
-H "X-Parse-REST-API-Key: GAv...SmK" \
-H "Content-Type: application/json" \
-d '{"username": "nonExistedUsername"}' \
https://api.parse.com/1/functions/IsNameAlreadyTaken
```

and the respond is the same: **WTF!!!**

```
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  100         61 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--   105{"result":"user was found. undefined"}
```

Any idea what is going on? is this a bug in Parse.com?

Answer (score 1):

Wild guess: I think that when user does not exist, you get `user === undefined` information (if it exists, you get the user object), so you have the information you need.

`error:` callback may be called only when connection fails or something like that. That's kind of standard handling in many cases in JavaScript.

Comment: Yes, maybe that is the case. That is weird because even the same Hector Ramos, a guy from parse, use this same code here: https://www.parse.com/questions/users-editing-other-users-in-javascript-sdk it make me think that Hector Ramos is wrong and doesn't even know its own product.

Comment: @lito: I would just send there your findings. However, given your observations, I don't see any other reasonable explanation..